# Rails: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, for-loop, error-handling

I want to build a for loop but I an this error.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

That is the part of the view, which gives me the error:

```
    <% @deadlines.each do |deadline| %>
        <% if Time.now < deadline.deadline %>
            <%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :enrolled, :value => true %>
              <%= f.submit "Anmeldung bestätigen", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Seems like @deadlines is not recognized, even though I already used the same loop in the Index view of the deadlines folder. How can I use the same variable in my homepage view?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the Controller, maybe it also gives you some information:

```
class DeadlinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_deadline, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /deadlines
  # GET /deadlines.json
  def index
    @deadlines = Deadline.all
  end

  # GET /deadlines/1
  # GET /deadlines/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /deadlines/new
  def new
    @deadline = Deadline.new
  end

  # GET /deadlines/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /deadlines
  # POST /deadlines.json
  def create
    @deadline = Deadline.new(deadline_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @deadline.save
        format.html { redirect_to @deadline, notice: 'Deadline was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @deadline }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @deadline.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /deadlines/1
  # PATCH/PUT /deadlines/1.json
  def update
    if @deadline.update(deadline_params)
      flash[:success] = "Die Deadline wurde erfolgreich aktualisiert."
      redirect_to deadlines_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Die Deadline wurde nicht aktualisiert."
    end
  end

  # DELETE /deadlines/1
  # DELETE /deadlines/1.json
  def destroy
    @deadline.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to deadlines_url, notice: 'Deadline was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_deadline
      @deadline = Deadline.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def deadline_params
      params.require(:deadline).permit(:deadline)
    end
end
```

Comment: where is homepage view action? are index and homepage is same?

Comment: What is the name of the file you are getting error? Can you share the log you get in the rails console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@deadlines` is empty now, use this `@deadlines = Deadline.all` to your homepage controller action and `each` block modify like this

```
<% if @deadlines.present? %>
    <% @deadlines.each do |deadline| %>
        <% if Time.now < deadline.deadline %>
            <%= form_for(current_user) do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :enrolled, :value => true %>
              <%= f.submit "Anmeldung bestätigen", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    Deadline is empty 
<% end %>
```

When `@deadlines` is empty then it will show **Deadline is empty**

Comment: That helped me perfectly!